# Ubuntu not reading CD/DVD drive

Tags: dvd, cd, cd-drive

When I insert a CD into my CD/DVD drive, Ubuntu doesn't seem to recognize the drive. When I run

```
sudo lshw -C disk
```

the only output I get is

```
  *-disk                    
       description: ATA Disk
       product: Hitachi HTS54756
       vendor: Hitachi
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: A50A
       serial: J2180053CE6YWD
       size: 596GiB (640GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096 signature=67d07c9b
```

Even in the /dev folder, the only file having anything to do with a CD/DVD drive is the sg0 file, and even that is of size 0B.

Comment: does the bios detect the disk drive? is this a laptop or a desktop? if desktop did you recently add the drive?

Comment: laptop, and I'm pretty sure bios detects it as I have played CDs before

Comment: well does it detaect it today? please check by going into BIOS.